# MYSQL error message when running through php but runs fine through DQ query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to figure out why the PHP code below gives me this error:

There was an error running the query

> [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'query2' at line 1]

If I run that query straight from MYSQL it runs no problem....
Please help, I've been staring at this code for the past 40 minutes...

```
if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$query2 = ("UPDATE phpbb_users SET user_password='$hashPW' WHERE user_id='$id' AND username='$username';");

if(!$result = $db->query(query2)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}    

$mysqli->close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
if(!$result = $db->query(query2)){
```

to

```
if(!$result = $db->query($query2)){
                         ^
```

`$` is missing in front of `$query2` variable

**On a side note:** your code in its current state is prone to sql-injections. Please consider using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `$` on the one line...

```
if ($db->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$query2 = ("UPDATE phpbb_users SET user_password='$hashPW' WHERE user_id='$id' AND username='$username';");

if (!$result = $db->query($query2)) {
  die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}   

$mysqli->close();
```